# How to save multiple form values as a consolidated String in Local Storage and retrieve them to be displayed on the browser

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a 'Notes' application which is basically a form that the user uses to enter 2 values, a name and a note.

I am displaying the 2 values as a 'consolidated note' on the browser with a delete button.

There can be any number of notes entered using this form.

How can I save the consolidated notes(i.e with Creator's name and the actual content of the note) in a string or array in the Local Storage and then retrieve it to be displayed on the browser when the browser reloads?

I understand that we save it using JSON.stringify and retrieve the data from the Local Storage using JSON.parse, but I'm unsure of how to save these multiple notes in the LOCAL Storage and retrieve them. Please help!

```
    function addNoteLocalStorage(){

    let notes = getNotesFromStorage();

    //creating the key-value pairs
    let creator = document.getElementById('creator').value;
    let note = document.getElementById('note').value;

    obj.creator = creator;
    obj.note = note;

    let jsonstring = JSON.stringify(obj);

    //create an array and push the string to the Object Array
    objArray.push(jsonstring);

    //store the new note
    localStorage.setItem('notes', objArray);
}
```

The above code saves more than one note in the Local Storage.

Currently, this is how the array looks when stored in LS.
{"creator":"dgfdxsf","note":"dsgdsg"},{"creator":"sfs","note":"asd"}

How can I retrieve the values back into an object so that I can display each creator and note associated with that creator ?

Comment: process to store a note,   get_localstore_notes > get_new_one_note > local_store_notes + new_one_note > put_localstore_notes, you need to create like array with objects in it, [{id:1, position:1, title: "xnote", body: "etc..."},{...}...{}]

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of the values you get from the form.

```
var obj = {
  creator : note
}
```

Now store this object in the local storage by stringifying in the same as you are doing (JSON.stringify). While retrieving, do a JSON.parse to retrieve the object.

If you have multiple objects like these, push them into an array and store that array in the local storage.

Comment: I have pushed them using an array, but when I try to retrieve it from Local Storage, how should I convert it back to creator and note separately?

Comment: What are you getting after retrieving from local storage ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert a string to a JSON string, so you can play with your data without the need for `stringify()` and `parse()`. If you save the notes as array, however, you will need to do that.

```
// Add Note to Local Storage
function addNoteLocalStorage(){

    //get saved notes. Set notes to empty string if it's the first time.
    let notes = localStorage.getItem('notes') || '';
    console.log("Notes return: "+notes);

    //creating the key-value pairs
    let creator = document.getElementById('creator').value;
    let note = document.getElementById('note').value;

    let consolidatedNotesString = creator+":"+note;

    //append the new note to the existing note
    notes += '\n'+ consolidatedNotesString;

    //store the new note
    localStorage.setItem('notes', notes);
}
```

With your edited question, you're saving notes in the form of array of objects, in which case you will of course need to `stringify` and `parse` back the notes. One issue with your current code is that you're converting to string the objects(notes) but you save the  array which contains the notes as it is. `stringify` the whole array instead and that's enough. And the way you access the stored notes is by the `getItem` method and `parse` it to get back the array. Make sure to save the empty `objArray` as `notes` in the local storage before calling `addNoteLocalStorage` function though, or you will need to check if `notes` are already in the storage before trying to parse it.

```
const objArray = [];
localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(objArray));

function addNoteLocalStorage(){

    objArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));

    //creating the key-value pairs
    let creator = document.getElementById('creator').value;
    let note = document.getElementById('note').value;

    //push the string to the Object Array
    objArray.push({creator, note});

    //store the new note
    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(objArray));
}

//And to get the first note and creator for example, you write like:

let noteArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
let firstNoteCreator = noteArray[0].creator;
let firstNote = noteArray[0].note;
```

Comment: Which one is the existing string? It will append the new note to the end of the previous notes.

Comment: Sorry, this works! So if I want to separate the string, I would just have to split the string at the ":" separator and convert it into an array so that I can display them separately on the browser?

Comment: all notes are a single string separated by a new line for each creator, and each line has a creator and the corresponding note separated by ":".  To get each note separately, you would first need to split the whole note with new line ("\n") and split with ":" to separate the note with the creator. But, if you clarify your goal for splitting, there might be a better solution.

Comment: Notecontent created by: Creator's name. This is how I would like to display it on the browser screen.